# how to get data from database in laravel with json?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, laravel-5

I am trying to make a verification in ajax if an email has already been taken in laravel 5.

This is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/EditEmail',
    data: form.serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 9000,
    error:function(data) {
        //verify if the user has already been taken 
    },
    success:function(data) {
        window.location.href=window.location.href;
    }   
});
```

This is the code in my controller :

```
public function EditEmail()
{    
    if(Hash::check(Input::get('ParolaActuala'),$parola) && count(User::where('email','=',$NoulEmail)->get()) == 0 )
    {
       DB::table('users')->where ('user_id',Auth::user()->user_id)->update(array('email' => Input::get('NoulEmail')));

       return Response::json(['success' => 'request succeeded'], 200);
    }    
}
```

So i already make the verification in my controller and user can't introduce the same email but i want to know how can i send data from my controller to ajax so i can make the verification there too.Does anybody have a solution ?

Comment: You're already sending data back, what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

**First option using statusCode :**

According to the Ajax documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you can do something like that :

```
statusCode: {
    200: function() {
      alert( "user found" );
    },
    404: function() {
      alert( "user not found" );
    }
 }
```

and returns in your controller :

```
// user does not exist
return Response::json(['status' => 'not_found'], 404);

//or if the user does exist
return Response::json(['status' => 'found'], 200);
```

**Second option using simple json data :**

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
    url: '/EditEmail',
    data: form.serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 9000,
    error:function(data) {
       //something went wrong with the request 
    },
    success:function(data) {
        if(data['status'] == "found") {
             alert( "user found" );
        } else {
             alert( "user not found" );
        }
    }   
});
```

and in your controller :

```
public function EditEmail()
{    
     if(Hash::check(Input::get('ParolaActuala'),$parola) && count(User::where('email','=',$NoulEmail)->get()) == 0 )
     {
          DB::table('users')->where ('user_id',Auth::user()->user_id)->update(array('email' => Input::get('NoulEmail')));

          return Response::json(['status' => 'not_found']);
     }    

     return Response::json(['status' => 'found']);
}
```

Comment: thanks man the solution with the statusCode works very fine for me!